# How do I link .cpp files to .hpp files in Xcode that were made outside of the project?

Tags: c++, xcode, header, linker

If you create a new .cpp file in Xcode, it will automatically create a corresponding .hpp file to link it to.  Is there a way I can do this manually (specifically with Xcode) with included files that were not created in the project? (the reason for this being so that I don't need to rewrite the same code for each project)

A simple code example would be...

in A.hpp:

```
class A{
   void method();
};
```

and in A.cpp:

```
#include "A.hpp"

void A::method(){/*do stuff*/};
```

and in main.cpp

```
#include <A.hpp>

int main(){
   A a;

   a.method();
}
```

Comment: In C++, you can compile your code using `-I <PATH_TO_HPP_LIB>`, e.g. `g++ -I <PATH_TO_HPP_LIB> app.cpp -o app.out`, try it out for xCode if you are able to modify the compile command. I am not familiar with xCode, though.

Comment: Are all of the files in the same folder? Other wise you might need to add the whole path the the .hpp file. also, in main.cpp it should be `#include "A.hpp"` not `#include <A.hpp>`

Comment: If you have the path to the directory in the 'include' search paths in Xcode, you have to use #include <A.hpp>

Comment: I don't understand.  Where does main.cpp come into the equation?

Comment: also, where does the app.out come from?